# Content provider issue while creating flavor in android application

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider, android-flavors

I had created the flavor for the android project.
Below is the changes i had implemented in gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.collegemobile.free.free"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "2.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions"default"
    productFlavors{
            paid{
                buildConfigField("String","paid","paid")
                applicationId 'com.collegemobile.paid.paid'
                 dimension "default"

            }
            free{
                buildConfigField("String", "free", "free") 
                applicationId 'com.collegemobile.free.free'
                dimension "default"

            }
        }
```

It works properly but now it shows issue for the content provider.
I did below changes in Manifest.xml file. In android:authorities="${applicationId} I had added $ applicationid.

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>




<provider
            android:name=".models.DataProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}"
            android:exported="false"
            android:syncable="true"></provider>
```

But it gives me below exception.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.collegemobile.paid.paid, PID: 29652
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.collegemobile.free.free: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.collegemobile.free.free.DataProvider from ProcessRecord{25cd8f9 29652:com.collegemobile.paid.paid.bbfg/u0a106} (pid=29652, uid=10106) that is not exported from UID 10103
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5876)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.collegemobile.itracks.bbfg.models.DataProvider from ProcessRecord{25cd8f9 29652:com.collegemobile.massmutual.bbfg/u0a106} (pid=29652, uid=10106) that is not exported from UID 10103
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4181)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5970)
        at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2592)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1828)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:786)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:752)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:710)
        at com.collegemobile.itracks.bbfg.BBFG.initOfflineMsgQueue(BBFG.java:342)
        at com.collegemobile.itracks.bbfg.BBFG.onCreate(BBFG.java:332)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5871)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProviderImpl(ActivityManagerService.java:12188)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerService.java:12585)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:357)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3291)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.collegemobile.free.free: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.collegemobile.free.free.DataProvider from ProcessRecord{25cd8f9 29652:com.collegemobile.paid.paid.bbfg/u0a106} (pid=29652, uid=10106) that is not exported from UID 10103` -- if I understand that error message correctly, your paid app seems to be advertising your free provider in its manifest. If you have not done so already, fully uninstall all copies of your app, then try running stuff again and see what your results are.

Comment: It works fine. Uninstall the app and install it again and it works. Thank you @CommonsWare